# A (non trivial) continuous map on a Banach space which is nowhere Frechet differentiable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, banach-spaces

Assume that $X$ is a Banach space. Is there a continuous map $f:X\to X$ such that $f$ is nowhere Frechet differentiable, but its restriction to every finite dimensional subspace is every where Frechet differentiable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://thaijmath.in.cmu.ac.th/index.php/thaijmath/article/viewFile/285/416

Fr\'echet differentiability implies G\^ateaux differentiability, but the converse is true only for finite-dimensional Banach spaces, in general. As an example, the mapping $f:L^1[0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\int_0^\pi\mbox{sin}(x(t))dt$ is every where G^ateaux differentiable, but nowhere Fr\'echet differentiable [9]

[9] M. Sova, Conditions for differentiability in linear topological spaces, Czechoslovak Math. J. (Russian) 16 (1966) 339­-362.

Comment: I think in finite (2) dimension there is a Gateaux differentiable function whih is not Frechet differentiable. so in finite dimension, these two are not equivalent. :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Comment: In the context of the paper the first statement was probably only for differentiation of norms. It seems to me that this does not affect this specific example.

Comment: Gateaux differentiability implies Frechet differentiability for Lipschitz mappings on finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Notice that non separability of $L_1^*$ is essentially for the example user46855 gave. Preiss' differentiability theorem says that every real valued Lipschitz function on a space with separable dual has a point of Frechet differentiability.

Comment: @BillJohnson Prof. Johnson Thank you for your 2 interesting comments

Comment: @user46855 thank you for your answer and the references

Comment: David Preiss commented to me that if you take $x\mapsto (f_k(x_k))_k$ on $\ell_2$ with $f_k$ suitable approximations to $|\cdot |$, you get a nowhere Frechet differentiable, everywhere Gateaux differentiable, mapping on $\ell_2$.